# Three-finger undo gesture with custom undo manger

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, ios13, nsundomanager

I'm trying to handle the three-finger gesture with a custom undo manager. Using the default undo manager provided by the window, resolved via the UIResponder chain works flawlessly. As soon as I try to use an own undo manager in a view controller I run into issues. (Background: I want to switch between different managers depending on the state of the view, so I can't use the single undo manager provided by the window.)

What I did:

- override `undoManager` in my view controller and return an own instance
- override `canBecomeFirstResponder` and return `true`
- set the VC to be the first responder on `viewDidAppear` (I also tried different places for that)

What I observe:

- three-finger swipes do *not* trigger `undo` on my undo manager, but on the window's
- the shake-to-undo gesture *does* trigger `undo` on my VC's undo manager

Now the funny part:
If I add a `UITextField` (or `UITextView`) to my view, tell it to become the first responder and immediately after let my VC become first responder again, the 3-finger gesture *works*! So it seems the text field is telling the system *something* when it becomes first responder that tells the 3-finger gesture observer to not use the window's undo manager. And when resigning first responder, the duty falls correctly to my VC.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you overriding the `undoManager` property of the `UITextField`/`UITextView`s? Otherwise, they return their own instance (see [`UIResponder.undoManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiresponder/1621122-undomanager)).

Comment: No, I don't override the undo manager of the `UITextField/UITextView`. Initially there shouldn't be a `UITextField` or `UITextView` in the view hierarchy at all, but I noticed if I add one of them to my view, tell it to become the first responder and immediately after let my view controller become first responder again, the three-finger gesture uses my custom undo manager from my view controller to undo.